# How to create a trigger to verify if a record is not exists?

Tags: mysql

I'm using version  5.5.47 (Ubuntu) of mysql. I'm trying create a trigger to check before insert on table. My idea is: If value of `LoginName` column  and  value of `Email` column exists, insert a new record won't be implemented.

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MemberProfile` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `LoginName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Birthday` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Gender` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1: nam , 2 nu',
  `Address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ProfileID` text,
  `ProfileURL` text,
  `AvatarImageURL` text,
  `CoverImageURL` text,
  `ActiveTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;
```

**I have done this:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER verifyExists BEFORE INSERT ON MemberProfile
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.Email,NEW.LoginName not in (
            select *
            From MemberProfile AS A  
            where (NEW.LoginName = A.LoginName and NEW.Email = A.Email)
        ) THEN 
           CALL `Insert not allowed`;

        END IF;
    END;
```

**error:**

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'NEW.LoginName not in (
>               select *
>               From MemberProfile AS ' at line 4

In my opinion, NEW.[columns] is a argument from insert action. I don't know exactly this. Can anyone help?

Comment: why was my post negatived?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a trigger for this. You can implement this functionality as a unique key constraint:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX username_email ON MemberProfile (LoginName, Email);
```

Once this is in place, attempting to insert a row with a duplicate login name and email address will yield an error:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'username-test@example.com' for key 'username_email'
```

(As an aside: Keep in mind this constraint will still allow multiple users to exist with the same username, or the same email -- just not both at once. This may not be a great idea.)

Comment: That work!. 
If I check 1 in 2 conditions ( or username or email exists ) , will I need to create a trigger such as  `( NEW.username = OLD.username or NEW.Email = OLD.Email)`?.

Comment: @Ntlzz93 No, you don't need a trigger for that either. Just create two unique indexes: one on `LoginName`, the other on `Email`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Email varchar(255),
DECLARE @LoginName varchar(255),
SELECT @Email= INSERTED.Email FROM INSERTED
SELECT @LoginName = INSERTED.LoginName FROM INSERTED
IF @Email,@LoginName not in (
     select *
     From MemberProfile AS A  
    where ( @LoginName = A.LoginName and @Email = A.Email)
) THEN 
     CALL `Insert not allowed`;
END IF;
END;
```